# AndroidX package android.support.design.R does not exist

Tags: android, androidx

When I convert my Project to AndroidX I run into

```
error: package android.support.design.R does not exist
                     android.support.design.R.styleable.FloatingActionButton_Behavior_Layout);
```

any clue how to solve it ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I found the solution, simply replace this line

```
android.support.design.R.
```

with

```
com.google.android.material.R.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just remove `android.support.design` from start of it.Android Studio added appropriate import i needed.

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, using react native, it was related to a library, react-native-snackbar.
I uninstalled and resinstalled react-native-snackbar and it worked.

`npm uninstall react-native-snackbar`

`npm i react-native-snackbar`

Comment: it could be that a bug was fixed between the old version I was using 2.3.1 and the new version 2.3.2